# Why does a SQLAlchemy session commit make my code appear to stop (after creating a table?)?

Tags: python-3.x, session, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a module to log stuff to a database using SQLAlchemy (SQLAlchemy==1.3.5) and Python 3.6.8.

I try to add a log into the table.

If the table doesn't exist I catch the 'Table does not exist' error and then create the table (which works fine).

The issue is that it fails when I retry adding the same item to the session. It seems the 'commit' causes it to just stop in its tracks.

I did try to use the 'exc.NoSuchTableError' exception but that didn't seem to pick up that the table didn't exist. I also tried various combinations of using just flush or just commit but results are similar as in the output.

I have a separate test.py file containing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ail

add_to_log = ail.add_to_log(
    tool='ansible',
    component='system management',
    level=6,
    description="This is a test message!",
)
```

The ail.py module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_filters import apply_filters

import pprint
import time
import re

def add_to_log(tool, component, description, level=6):
    """

        Add an entry to the 'logs' table.

        E.g: add_to_log = log.add_to_log(
                 tool='cims_import.py',
                 component='database',
                 level=6,
                 description="The CIMS import script was unable to access the CIMS database.",
             )

    :param tool: Tool the log item is for, e.g.: cims, spectrum, capm, nfa, etc.
    :param component: The component the log relates to, e.g.: 'api', 'ssh' or 'backups'
    :param level: 0=Emergency, 1=Alert, 2=Critical, 3=Error, 4=Warning, 5=Notice, 6=Informational, 7=Debug
    :param description: Description of event added to the logs.
    :return: dictionary containing results, e.g.: {'action': 'added'}
             In the event of an error, a dict containing {'error': '<error_description>'} will be returned.
    """

    try:

        # Try to add log item to the 'logs' table:
        logged_item = Log(
            tool=tool,
            component=component,
            level=level,
            description=description,
        )
        s2s.add(logged_item)
        s2s.commit()
        return {'action': 'added'}

    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:

        print("First attempt failed, creating database!")

        # Unable to add the log item:
        if re.search(r"Table '.*' doesn't exist", str(e)):

            print("Table issue")
            # The 'logs' table does not exist - try to create a new one:
            try:
                Base.metadata.tables["logs"].create(bind=s2)
            except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
                return {'error': e}
            else:
                print("Table success")
                try:
                    print("Try add item again")
                    # Try to add the log item again:
                    logged_item = Log(
                        tool=tool,
                        component=component,
                        level=level,
                        description=description
                    )
                    print("going to add")
                    s2s.add(logged_item)
                    print("going to commit")
                    s2s.commit()
                    print("committed!")
                    return {'action': 'added'}

                except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
                    return {'error': e}

        else:

            return {'error': e}


s2 = db.create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqlconnector://user:password@server:port/s2db', pool_recycle=3600, echo=True)

session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=s2)
s2s = session()
Base = declarative_base()

class Log(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'logs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    tool = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    component = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    level = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=0, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), server_default=db.func.now())
```

I make sure the 'logs' table does not exist in the DB and run it:

Logging on the first run is:

```
(venv) [user@server venv]$ ./test.py 
2019-07-11 23:40:32,608 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2019-07-11 23:40:32,608 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:40:32,611 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2019-07-11 23:40:32,611 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:40:32,613 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2019-07-11 23:40:32,613 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:40:32,614 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-11 23:40:32,614 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:40:32,615 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-11 23:40:32,615 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:40:32,616 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-07-11 23:40:32,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO logs (tool, component, level, description) VALUES (%(tool)s, %(component)s, %(level)s, %(description)s)
2019-07-11 23:40:32,618 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'tool': 'ansible', 'component': 'system management', 'level': 6, 'description': 'This is a test message!'}
2019-07-11 23:40:32,628 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
First attempt failed, creating database!
Table issue
2019-07-11 23:40:32,688 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE logs (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        tool VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        component VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        level INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
        created DATETIME DEFAULT now(), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (id)
)


2019-07-11 23:40:32,688 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:40:33,034 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
Table success
Try add item again
going to add
going to commit
(venv) [user@server venv]$
```

So why does it not commit or even put additional error messages after 'going to commit'?

So at this stage the table itself has been created but no log entry is present.

If I run it again (with the table now created) any number of times it works fine:

```
(venv) [user@server venv]$ test.py
2019-07-11 23:42:45,144 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2019-07-11 23:42:45,144 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:42:45,149 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2019-07-11 23:42:45,149 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:42:45,153 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2019-07-11 23:42:45,153 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:42:45,155 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-11 23:42:45,155 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:42:45,156 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-11 23:42:45,157 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:42:45,158 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-07-11 23:42:45,161 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO logs (tool, component, level, description) VALUES (%(tool)s, %(component)s, %(level)s, %(description)s)
2019-07-11 23:42:45,161 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'tool': 'ansible', 'component': 'system management', 'level': 6, 'description': 'This is a test message!'}
2019-07-11 23:42:45,164 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
(venv) [user@server venv]$
```

It is almost as if the creation of the table has interfered with the session (s2s).

Can anyone offer any advice / help as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I watched a video on youtube and when they mentioned rollback I thought I had to roll back but it seems the session isn't meant to be a one session to rule them all (at least it doesn't look like it is meant to - from my limited knowledge - only started with SQLAlchemy this week!).

It looks like it is better to create and close sessions. This seems to have worked for me:

I removed the session setup under the global scope and just replaced the 2 'add log item to db' blocks to:

```
                # NOTE: setup new session:
                s2s = session()
                logged_item = Log(
                    tool=tool,
                    component=component,
                    level=level,
                    description=description
                )
                print("going to add")
                s2s.add(logged_item)
                print("going to commit")
                s2s.commit()
                print("committed!")
                # NOTE: close session:
                s2s.close()
                return {'action': 'added'}
```

Result:

```
(venv) [user@server venv]$ ./test.py 
2019-07-11 23:58:44,259 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
2019-07-11 23:58:44,259 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,264 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
2019-07-11 23:58:44,264 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,268 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2019-07-11 23:58:44,268 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,270 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-11 23:58:44,270 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,272 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-07-11 23:58:44,272 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,274 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-07-11 23:58:44,276 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO logs (tool, component, level, description) VALUES (%(tool)s, %(component)s, %(level)s, %(description)s)
2019-07-11 23:58:44,277 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'tool': 'ansible', 'component': 'system management', 'level': 6, 'description': 'This is a test message!'}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,278 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ROLLBACK
First attempt failed, creating database!
Table issue
2019-07-11 23:58:44,334 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine 
CREATE TABLE logs (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        tool VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        component VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        level INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
        created DATETIME DEFAULT now(), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (id)
)


2019-07-11 23:58:44,334 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,368 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
Table success
Try add item again
going to add
going to commit
2019-07-11 23:58:44,370 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-07-11 23:58:44,370 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO logs (tool, component, level, description) VALUES (%(tool)s, %(component)s, %(level)s, %(description)s)
2019-07-11 23:58:44,371 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'tool': 'ansible', 'component': 'system management', 'level': 6, 'description': 'This is a test message!'}
2019-07-11 23:58:44,374 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
committed!
(venv) [user@server venv]$
```